# SOQL to find which reports are accesed by what profile?

Tags: soql, permissions

How can I extract by means of soql or exchange app, which users or profiles, have access to which report folders?

Comment: View the report access levels?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to query which users or profiles have access to which report folders. Take a look at [this resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_folder.htm).

You could do a query such as this:

```
[SELECT AccessType,Type FROM Folder WHERE Type = 'Report']
```

That would tell you whether or not a folder is:

- Hidden—Folder is hidden from everyone.
- Public—Folder is accessible by all users.
- Shared—Folder is accessible only by a User in a particular Group or UserRole.

However, as the documentation states:

> The API doesn’t allow you to view, insert, or update which group or Role the Folder is shared with.

There was also a similar question asked [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hheuAAA) on the Salesforce Developer forums which had the same problem.

Hopefully I'm wrong on this, however. But from what research I've found it doesn't look like you're in luck.